# Two tables that have keys to each other on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have the following classes:

```
public class Condition 
{
    public int Id {get;set; }
    public Condition ParentCondition {get;set;}
    public Action ParentAction {get;set;}
    public string Whatever {get;set;}
}

public class Action 
{
    public int Id {get;set; }
    public Condition ParentCondition {get;set;}
    public Action ParentAction {get;set;}
    public string Whatever {get;set;}
}
```

So both, the condition and the action may have either a condition or an action as a parent (or none if both are null)

I tried to put this onto a SQL database but lost somehow. So something I would want to achieve would be something like (pseudo code)

TABLE `Condition`:

```
int ConditionParent
int ActionParent
```

Table `Action`:

```
int ConditionParent
int ActoinParent
```

I tried using fluent api:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Condition>()
                .ToTable("Condition")
                .HasOptional(c => c.ParentAction)
                .WithRequired(a => a.ParentCondition);
```

But when I do this, the `Action` table looks fine, but the migration code for the condition has no column for an action parent at all.

What has to be changed?

Comment: my bet is to make use of `Entity Framework Power Tools` instead of researching for solutions; Create tables and click the options inside your Visual Studio, you should know what you should write :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx

Comment: That seems a bit like surrendering. I don't want to create a database to create code to create a database afterwards.

Comment: yes, i agree but there are certain scenarios which saves your time from researching code what has to be written :)

Comment: @OleAlbers what is `BaseCondition` ? Add its code ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Sorry. Mistyping. By reducing my realworld-problem to the required bits I forgot about renaming that class. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by explicitly adding Ids:

```
public class Condition 
{
    public int Id {get;set; }
    public int? ParentConditionId {get;set;}
    public virtual Condition ParentCondition {get;set;}
    public int? ParentActionId {get;set; }
    public virtual Action ParentAction {get;set;}
    public string Whatever {get;set;}
}

public class Action 
{
    public int Id {get;set; }
    public int ParentConditionId {get;set;}
    public virtual Condition ParentCondition {get;set;}
    public int? ParentActionId {get;set;}
    public virtual Action ParentAction {get;set;}
    public string Whatever {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: If you didn't change the mapping this doesn't solve anything. The column isn't used by EF.

Answer (score 0):

The `Conditions` table *does* have a column for its parent action! It's the primary key, that is a foreign key to `Action` at the same time.

Look at the (essential) creation code for the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actions](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentAction_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Actions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Actions] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Actions_dbo.Actions_ParentAction_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentAction_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Actions] ([Id])

-- Here: primary key Id is foreign key to Condition
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Actions] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Actions_dbo.Conditions_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Conditions] ([Id])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conditions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentCondition_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Conditions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Conditions] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Conditions_dbo.Conditions_ParentCondition_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentCondition_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Conditions] ([Id])
```

This is because `Action`-`Condition` is a 1:1 association. EF always implements required 1:1 associations by this PK/FK construction. It makes sense: an `Action` can't exist without its required `Condition` parent. The best way to guarantee that is for `Action` to "borrow" `Condition`'s PK value.